# react-native-hsm-maps implemented but shows blank?

Tags: android, react-native, huawei-mobile-services

I need to implement Huawei maps in my application, the version that I installed in my `package.json` file is:

```
"@hmscore/react-native-hms-map": "^5.2.0-302"
```

after installation I tried to do what ever docs says so you can see my configs in different files below:

```js
<HMSMap
  mapType={MapTypes.NORMAL}
  style={{height: 200}}
  camera={{target: {latitude: 41, longitude: 29}, zoom: 11}}
  onMapReady={(e) => console.log('HMSMap onMapReady: ', e.nativeEvent)} // btw this event never called.
/>
```

inside `build.gradle` file in android I add the `maven { url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/' }` inside `buildscripts => repositories` and `allprojects => repositories`, also in dependencies I add `classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.2.1.301'`

inside `build.gradle` in `android > app` file I added `apply plugin: "com.huawei.agconnect"` also I added `config` object as below in `signingConfigs`. then I added  `implementation 'com.huawei.hms:maps:5.0.0.300'` inside dependencies of this file

```
config {
            storeFile file('***.keystore')
            storePassword '*****'
            keyAlias '******'
            keyPassword '*******'
        }
```

and then I added this 2 inside `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.huawei.hms.client.appid" android:value="appid=*******" />
 <uses-permission android:name="com.huawei.appmarket.service.commondata.permission.GET_COMMON_DATA"/>
```

I have other permissions which docs says as well..

and the problem is when I run the project the map doesn't show and only shows a blank space which is related to the height which is 200 inside styles. also when I log the event of `onMapReady` method it doesn't log. seems that map isn't ready at all. how can I debug this or understand which part of config or code is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

1 Make sure the MAP kit is enabled in you app from Huawei Developer.

2 Make sure you add the dependency for Map Kit in Build.Gradle app.

3 Make sure the SHA-256 certificate fingerprint that you entered in develeper is the same in the app. [docs link](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/config-agc-0000001050032216-V1)

4 Make sure that you entered the signingConfigs in the build.gradle app.

For details, you could follow [this guide](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-Plugin-Guides-V1/integrating-sdk-0000001050034173-V1) to check the configuration.